# vbs combining consts

Tags: vbscript

This is a quick (and probably stupid) question but if I have two consts string how can I build the next const from the previous const i.e.

```
Const PATH_SRC = "some path\"
Const PATH_SRC_FILES = PATH_SRC & "files\"
```

I know you may say a const is a const but looking for a quick solution.  This is being performed in a vbs script.

Thanks

Comment: A constant is a constant because it does not change, if you want it to change it's a variable.

Comment: Removed 'vb6' tag since question specifically asks about VBScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I recall correctly from my VBS days; you can't do that in VBS. A constant can only be set to a literal.

Comment: Correct, and you can't do it in VB6 either. (For some reason the question is tagged VBScript and VB6.)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible!

```
Const PATH_SRC = "some path\"
execute "Const PATH_SRC_FILES =""" & PATH_SRC & "files\" & """"
msgbox PATH_SRC_FILES
```