# Understanding Const expression in VBScript

Tags: syntax, vbscript, constants, declaration

Well, I try to understand limitations in `Const` *expressions* in `VBScript`. I was not able to use anything except literals. What [the docs say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16twy8ed%28v=VS.84%29.aspx) is:

> *Literal or other constant, or any combination that includes all
>   arithmetic or logical operators except* **Is**.

So, if "that includes all arithmetic or logical operators" then logically I expect I can do something like this:

```
Const X = (1 + 2)
```

But that brings the error "Expected literal constant". I found an interesting answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9424941) that allows one to cheat, at some level, so the above can be done with:

```
Execute "Const X = " & (1 + 2)
```

But my question is about standard constant declaration. If by chance the docs said something like "expression could be ONLY literal", then I would never ask.
So what Else I can use (besides literal)?

Comment: Good old Microsoft ambiguity. If you do the first one without the parentheses, what happens?

Comment: test.vbs(1, 16) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected literal constant

Comment: Thanks for rapid reply. If cut parentheses, no difference, same error

Comment: The docs are incorrect; likely whoever wrote the documentation was confused with the Visual Basic feature, which does allow complex expressions. We decided that constant folding in VBScript was unnecessary and would take resources away from more important features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script56.chm says the following in the Remarks section:

> Constants are public by default. Within procedures, constants are always private; their visibility can't be changed. Within a script, the default visibility of a script-level constant can be changed using the Private keyword.
>
> To combine several constant declarations on the same line, separate each constant assignment with a comma. When constant declarations are combined in this way, the Public or Private keyword, if used, applies to all of them.
>
> You can't use variables, user-defined functions, or intrinsic VBScript functions (such as Chr) in constant declarations. By definition, they can't be constants. *You also can't create a constant from any expression that involves an operator*, that is, only simple constants are allowed. Constants declared in a Sub or Function procedure are local to that procedure. A constant declared outside a procedure is defined throughout the script in which it is declared. You can use constants anywhere you can use an expression.

The bit in italics above makes a nonsense of the "or any combination that includes all arithmetic or logical operators except Is" claim.

Comment: Huh, openly contradiction :) So, what you suggest is that Remarks section is correct one, right?

Comment: That'd be my take on it, yes. Maybe it was that two (or more?) people wrote the docs and that they didn't communicate well, or that the Const notation was going to be more powerful but never quite got there in the end. Either way, we've got a contradiction and my experience with VBScript favours the Remarks reading.

Comment: I'll rely on your experience and accept this as answer, thanks.